# Will I not be able to descend with an airfoil that stalls at -0.5°?

Tags: airfoil

This stats says this airfoil stalls at -0.5°,does this means if I have this airfoil as a wing ,I won't even be able to  have a descent aoa?

[image]!

Comment: The stall angle entry doesn’t make sense - stall should occur just above the angle for max CL which is given as 12.5°. Max L/D (best glide, not stall) is at -0.5°.

Comment: Got to be a typo. You can't get to Max Cl at 12.5deg if the wing stalls at -0.5deg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't believe everything that a computer tells you.

This airfoil is listed in the [airfoiltools](http://www.airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=stcyr24-il#polars) site, and I took the liberty to copy its XFOIL results here:

[image: Airfoiltools plots for Bartels 35-IIIC]

I selected the Reynolds numbers 500,000 and 1,000,000, which should be at the low end for a man-carrying aircraft. As you can see, the stall angle of attack is at 15° and the maximum lift coefficient is between 1.7 and 1.75. To achieve a lift coefficient of 1.89 with that airfoil will need a much higher Reynolds number, but max. L/D is already around 120.