# What does leading edge radius mean?

Tags: terminology, airfoil

[image]

What does leading edge radius mean amongst these parameters of a st cyr 24 airfoil?

Comment: "st cyr 24"  Please add more description for that.

Comment: The radius of curvature at the leading edge?

Comment: @CrossRoads: See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52365/will-i-not-be-able-to-descend-with-an-airfoil-that-stalls-at-0-5) for an explanation. [Here](http://www.airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=stcyr24-il#polars) it is on airfoiltools.

Comment: Ok, so "st cyr 24" is an airfoil shape then.  I didn't make that connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [radius](https://epoxyworks.com/index.php/how-to-loft-airfoil-sections/) of the leading edge as a percentage of chord.

[image]